# What's the word to refer to the "ringing" sound of the bell in Japanese schools?

Tags: single-word-requests

Unlike the west, school bells don't ring but make a melodious series of *dinging* sounds. What's the word to refer to them?

Example sentence:

> The school bell still __ in my ears.

Chiming? Ringing?

Here's the sound: https://youtu.be/xEQ3c8xyLZc

Comment: Don't you think a sound clip is in order here? Otherwise, only users who have attended Japanese school, or watched a documentary about them will be able to answer

Comment: I've heard all manner of school bell sounds in the US, so it's hard to guess what you're talking about.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I added a YouTube video with the sound.

Comment: Sounds similar to a [synthetic] grandfather clock [striking the hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQTp0Bh09ic) and here's [Big Ben](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9wWBjnaEck) Chiming? ding-dong?

Comment: Oh, don't acknowledge my help at all. By the way it's **chiming**, exactly how I spelled it,  only one *m* is needed, not three.

Comment: Typical clock chime, it sounds like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of "melodious series of *dinging* sounds" is called a **chime**.

> 1 A bell or a metal bar or tube, typically one of a set tuned to produce a melodious series of ringing sounds when struck.
>
> 1.1 A melodious ringing sound produced by striking a set of chimes.
> ‘I hear the chimes of the hour from the courthouse’

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/chime)

There is a corresponding verb form.

As for filling in the blank in your sentence, a past simple sounds most natural; you could say 'chimed'. Or 'was still chiming'.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly unusual about that bell sound and any standard "bell" verb will work.

That said, [for practical purposes, things only "**ring** in your ears"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+in+my+ears%2C+chiming+in+my+ears&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3); [bells mostly "ring"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+bell+*_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3); and any other verb you use is going to sound poetic ("chimed", "tolled", "echoed", "called"...) or unusual ("dinned", "sounded"...).

If you really want to call out the different musical quality of the "Japanese" bell, you'd use description or, failing that, adjectives.